# Jquery/Ajax to get database using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML page that is too big to post on here, however I'll just post the ajax/jquery I am using to try and access the PHP file variables.

**threadPage.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            
        $.ajax({
        url : '/ThreadCreation.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data: {'titles': titles}
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function (data) {
           console.log(data) /
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    })  

</script>

<!-- bunch of html -->
```

So essentially I am trying to get the variable from the `ThreadCreation.php` in JSON form. It should be in an array so that I can loop through it in the HTML file.

**ThreadCreation.php**

```
<?php

    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'main_database';

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username , $password,$db);
    
    if (!$conn){
        die("unable to connect");
    }

    
   $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT title FROM thread");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $titles[] = $row['title'];

   echo json_encode($titles);
?>
```

I will repeat though, that this HTML file is only getting information from the database through PHP. So there is no form submission here.

I keep getting that 'titles is not defined'. This makes sense because there is not titles defined in the HTML, however I am unsure how to construct my ajax request to collect the data, as this format is all I have seen people use.

Comment: You should try: 
```var titles = <?php echo json_encode($titles);?>```

Comment: @HoangHiey even if they are in separate files?

Comment: @kongar Close bracket before echo.

Comment: are u tried to use `dataType : 'json'` instead of `dataType : 'jsonp'`

Comment: @RobinSingh its giving me syntax error. Is this correct ``var titles = <?php (echo json_encode($titles));?>``

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic Yes, with json I was getting Access Control Error

Comment: @kongar that is not correct.

Comment: what is `titles` here i.e : `data: {'titles': titles}` ? its undefined .

Comment: @Swati Thats my issue, Its not defined but I cant request php without some data. So i am not sure what to do.

Comment: why do you think you cannot call php via ajax without data ? did you tried calling your backend without that whole part ?

Comment: @swati When i do no data so ``data: {'title': ''}`` i get this printed in my console log ``jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/RuneScape_website/RS.com/aff/runescape/forums/ForumThread/ThreadCreation.php?callback=jQuery35107455217596951675_1608704874312&title=&_=1608704874313``

Comment: You don't need ```data: {'titles': titles}```, remove it from the javascript code

Comment: @HoangHieu It still goes to error. I removed it from the code. I get the error i mentioned above your comment. Its a 404 error, but that url does exist

Comment: when you type that url in your address bar does that page show ? or try removing that `/` from `'/ThreadCreation.php'` see if that works .

Comment: @Swati I fixed the path there was a typo. but I still get the error alert. The GET error is gone but now just the error is occuring.

Comment: The error is now different from question, please review the request.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @HoangHieu what error are you getting now ?

Answer (score 0):

Mention empty array first just to prevent error in case you have no data
in database then empty array will proceed.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT title FROM thread");

$titles = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    array_push($titles,$row['title']); // Push data in empty array
}
echo json_encode($titles);
```